# What's the most straight-forward way to install MythTV with a full desktop environment?

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

Install Ubuntu and then add MythTV?  Install Mythbuntu and add desktop environment packages?

Also, would Unity cause problems?  I'm willing to switch to something different (like Gnome).

Also, would it work any better if I switched to something like Mint?

Comment: Download the Ubuntu specific variant Mythbuntu.

Comment: Unity (actually Compiz) causes issues with MythTV unless you enable legacy mode in Compiz. I'd suggest installing Mythbuntu, as it uses XFCE for the desktop environment (not sure what you mean by full desktop environment).

Comment: I'm disappointed to hear that Compiz and MythTV conflict.  If I were to create two different login session options, one with Compiz and one for using MythTV, would that still cause issues?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Mythbuntu is the most *straightforward* way to get MythTV and a full desktop environment, as it already comes with the lightweight XFCE desktop environment.

Straight from [the source](http://www.mythbuntu.org/):

> Mythbuntu uses the XFCE desktop. All unnecessary standard Ubuntu applications such as LibreOffice, Evolution, and a full Gnome desktop are not installed in a default Mythbuntu install. If at any time a user wants to, they can install ubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-desktop, or xubuntu-desktop and add a full desktop onto their installation. This can easily be done via the Mythbuntu Control Centre.